# Visual Studio Code - accidentally clicked Shift+Alt+D (Download Settings)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally clicked on Shift+Alt+D (Download Settings) which started some process
started some extension that was installed on my VSC (dont know why):
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

and reset all my Visual Studio Code settings - theme color, shortcuts, fonts size, appearance etc....
someone know how I can revert it?

[image]

**and this is the log that I got :(((**

```
Realtime Extension Download Summary
--------------------
TOTAL EXTENSIONS : 2



[x] - EXTENSION: prettier-vscode - INSTALLING

[x] - EXTENSION: prettier-vscode INSTALLED.
      1 OF 2 INSTALLED


[x] - EXTENSION: vscode-sshfs - INSTALLING

[x] - EXTENSION: vscode-sshfs INSTALLED.
      2 OF 2 INSTALLED

CODE SETTINGS SYNC DOWNLOAD SUMMARY
Version: 3.4.3
--------------------
GitHub Token: 23423423
GitHub Gist: 34234234
GitHub Gist Type: Secret

Restarting Visual Studio Code may be required to apply color and file icon theme.
--------------------
Files Downloaded:
  extensions.json > extensions.json
  keybindings.json > keybindings.json
  settings.json > settings.json

Extensions Ignored:
  No extensions ignored.

Extensions Removed:
  comment-tagged-templates v0.3.0
  path-intellisense v1.4.2
  bracket-pair-colorizer v1.0.61
  es7-react-js-snippets v2.7.1
  auto-rename-tag v0.1.3
  vscode-styled-components v0.0.29
  vs-color-picker v1.0.0
  material-ui-snippets v3.2.0
  html-css-class-completion v1.19.0

Extensions Added:
  prettier-vscode v2.3.0
  vscode-sshfs v1.16.3
--------------------
Done.
```

Comment: This is not a standard VSC command, not in v1.44.2 or v1.46. Which extension has added this command?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Comment: very unfortunate the extension uses predefined shortcut keys and not even a double key. These predefined keys should be removed, to much risk of a typo if you meant to hit F or S. does it not keep a backup 1 or 2 deep?

Comment: Didn't find any backup...